# Do I need to redirect old style URLs for SEO when both work?

Tags: url, 301-redirect, link-structure

I have old URL structure pages indexed in Google that are ranked well against the keywords. Now I have cleaned the URL structures and the new URLs have more potential to get ranked higher. Both pages are currently live.

**Old URL** (*Ranked higher*)**:** http://www.example.com/products.asp?category=42

**New URL:** http://www.example.com/products/new-category

Do I have to implement 301 redirects?
If I do, will my old URL rankings drop?
Will they be replaced with the new URLs in the search results?

Answer (score 4):

If you leave both on for the same page without redirection then the ranking will drop.

It is recommended that you should redirect your old URL to the new one.

Canonical: If you may have difficulty implementing redirection (301), you can place canonical in old URL or in both like:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/products/new-category" />
```

It means your clean URL will be the preferred URL.

Ranking: You may see a minor drop for a temporary period of time and then it will come back to new URL.

Comment: You should suggest canonicals too.   Redirects aren't a "must" because of the alternatives.

Comment: Agree. Missed on canonical part completely. Answer amended.

Comment: What TopQnA says is correct, but I would do both a 301 redirect and add a canonical tag.